# C++ external file read: I know how to find and read a string, findMe. But how do I deal with findMei (finding any number, i, of the string)?

Tags: c++, stream

Apologies in advance, because I suspect this may be a silly question.

I have written a function for reading in data from an external file.  I then use the data to perform calculations using other code I have written.

The function works by finding a data label that looks like this:

```
 const std::string findMe = "<dataLabel>";
```

Each time I want to find data, I replace dataLabel with the label of whichever data I need from the file.

Here's what I want to do.
I don't want to have to write in the label of the data I want each time.  I want to be able to do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < anyNumberOfDataSets; i++)  
{
    findMe = "<dataLabeli>"; 
    // Then run function for reading in data, put data into a vector.
}
```

I could then add any number of data sets to my external file, give each one the title
, and have each data set read into a vector.

The problem is, I simply can't figure out how to write `findMe = "<dataLabeli>"`.  Is this even possible?

I have tried things like, `findMe = "<dataLabel" << i <<`, but no luck!

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you've already got the right answer, so this is just trying to help you with solving such problems in the future:

Your core problem here is to convert the integer `i` into a string `s` (if you've done this, than you just do `findMe = "<datalabel"; findMe += s; findMe += ">";`.

Googling for [c++ convert integer into string](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=c%2B%2B+convert+interger+into+string) will give you [this](http://notfaq.wordpress.com/2006/08/30/c-convert-int-to-string/) as the first result. Problem solved.

This is not saying "use google before/instead of asking", it's rather "try to identify the core problem".

Comment: Thanks a lot davka.  It works now and I really appreciate your help and your tip for the future.  I could not have figured it out myself.  Sorry for the silly question, and I promise to make it up by doing my time with newbie questions if I ever figure out what I'm doing!  Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

It is very hard to understand what you mean, but I guess you want this

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>    

for (int i = 0; i < anyNumberOfDataSets; i++)  
{
    std::ostringstream strm;
    strm << "<dataLabel" << i << ">";
    const std::string findMe = strm.str();
    //...  
    //proceed with searching findMe     
}
```

You can read more about string streams, for instance, [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, Armen.  This did not do it for me because of a compiler bug that I need to figure out, but it's a useful approach that I'll keep in mind for the future.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
using namespace boost;
findMe = str(format("<dataLabel%d>") % i);
```

This will substitute `%d` with the value of `i`, formatted like `printf()` does.